# How can I use explicit Type Casting in C# linq

Tags: c#

I should try this code But it didn't work properly.Please Give solution on this code

```
 var patientList = (from b in GBill.GetList()
                           join p in GPatient.GetList()                               
                           on b.PatientId equals p.patientid

                           select new { 
                                        patientid = p.patientid,
                                        patientName = p.patientName,
                                        address = p.address,
                                        age = p.age,
                                        BillId = b.BillId,
                                        GrandTotal = b.GrandTotal,
                                        salutation= p.salutation =="Mr."?"Male":"FeMale",
                                        VisitNo = b.VisitNo ==Convert.ToInt32( b.VisitNo >1 ? "Old" : "New")
                           }).ToList();
```

It show an error on Visit No;

[image]

Comment: Never mind LINQ to Entities, how are you expecting this to work? `Convert.ToInt32( b.VisitNo >1 ? "Old" : "New")`, when clearly, those are not numbers?

Comment: `(b.VisitNo >1 ? "Old" : "New")` has ternary  operator (`?:`). here it will return `"Old"` if b.VisitNo is greater than 1. else it will be `"New"`. and you are trying to convert these strings into int.

Comment: Post errors as Text, not as an image. And when you first search on that text you will find many duplicate questions already asked here.

Comment: thank you guys.. I remove this convert.ToInt32 and try this  VisitNo = b.VisitNo == 1 ? "New" : "Old" and its work